# Trying to delete lines beginning with a specific string from files where the file meets a target condition, in bash/linux

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a bash script that will run a couple of times a minute. What I would like it to do is find all files in a specified directory that contain a specified string, and search that list of files and delete any line beginning with a different specific string (in this case it's

Here's what I've tried s far, but they aren't working:

```
ls -1t /the/directory | head -10 | grep -l "qualifying string" * | sed -i '/^<meta/d' *'
ls -1t /the/directory | head -10 | grep -l "qualifying string" * | sed -i '/^<meta/d' /the/directory'
```

The only reason I added in the head -10 is so that every time the script runs, it will start by only looking at the 10 most recent files. I don't want it to spend a lot of time searching needlessly through the entire directory since it will be going through and removing the line many times a minute.

The script has to be run out of a different directory than the files are in. Also, would the modified date on the files change if the `"<meta"` string doesn't exist in the file?

Comment: Are you writing a script (file) or are you writing a single command? If you you're going to go through the trouble of making an executable script, I would recommend doing this in a more modern scripting language (ruby, python, etc). But that's just my preference. I find bash really cumbersome for things like this.

Comment: I was going down the path of making an executable bash script that would basically use the one linux command. If I were to use any other language it would have to be Python.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of problem with this part of the command...

```
ls -1t /the/directory | head -10 | grep -l "qualifying string" * ...
```

First, you appear to be trying to pipe the output of `ls ... | head -10` into grep, which would cause `grep` to search for "qualifying string" in the output of `ls`.  Except then you turn around and provide `*` as a command line argument to grep, causing it to search in all the files, and completely ignoring the `ls` and `head` commands.

You probably want to read about the `xargs` commands, which reads a list of files on *stdin* and then runs a given command against that list.  For example, you ought to be able to generate your file list like this:

```
ls -1t /the/directory | head -10 | 
  xargs grep -l "qualifying string"
```

And to apply `sed` to those files:

```
ls -1t /the/directory | head -10 | 
  xargs grep -l "qualifying string" |
  sed -i 's/something/else/g'
```

Modifying the files with `sed` will update the modification time on the files.

Comment: Dont you need to remove all the other fields generated in ls-lt before passing to `xargs` ? It will try opening `total` and fail

Comment: That's not lower-case-L, that's the number 1.  You may want to pick a browser font that makes that more obvious.  It's actually a no-op in this case, but the OP was using it.  When *not* piping `ls` to something else, `-1` forces a 1-column display, but this is the default behavior when piping (technically, "when output is not a TTY").

Comment: I tried the first part and didn't add the sed yet. I'm getting errors. It's listing the 10 most recent files, but like this: grep: filename: No such file or directory.

Comment: If your filenames contain spaces, you will need a slightly different mechanism.  If I run this locally, it works as I expect.

Comment: Ah! That must be it. The file names don't have spaces, but the directory does. I was using an escape character like this: /the\ directory/filename.html. Unfortunately I can't change the folder name to not use a space, I will have to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use globbing with the `*` character to expand file names and loop through the directory.

```
n=0
for file in /the/directory/*; do
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        grep "qualifying string" "$file" && sed -i '/^<meta/d' "$file"
        n=$((n+1))
    fi
    [ $n -eq 10 ] && break
done
```