# How to delete specific events log from log file in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have a log file that size is more than 100MB

There are more than 1M lines
below are 2 lines that in log file so I need to remove all lines beginning with **"SMS2128301"**   (only in 4 th column in the line)

8,16/05/01 00:00:07,8801879887676,**SMS2128301**,0,0,0,1462039208274617,0,dummy,,5,6,,0,0,,1,0,27,0,0,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0,8801879887676,SMS2128301,,,

8,16/05/01 00:00:10,8801821094128,**SMS2128301**,0,0,0,1462039210395674,0,dummy,,5,6,,0,0,,1,0,41,0,0,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0,8801821094128,SMS2128301,,,

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154231/trying-to-delete-lines-beginning-with-a-specific-string-from-files-where-the-fil?rq=1

Comment: hi piyush thanks for the response..actually I'm not good in linux commanding. so can you just tell  me the  command???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried somthing like this, but it would be slow I think:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE '%SMS2128301%'
```

As a test to view, then upgade to DELETE when sure. Backup table first obviously!

EDIT
Sorry miss read, thought it was MYSQL. What viewer are you using in Linux?

Comment: thanks.. in linux I used cat command and I can open that file in windows pc too

Comment: I see. Cat is excellent for viewing a files contents, but you are better using vim to edit. Firstly I would copy the log to make sure you don't make a mistake. Then open the file by navigating to the folder and typing `vim log_file_name.log` in vim press esc and type `:g/SMS2128301/d` this should search for all lines and delete the ones with this reference in.

Comment: I should also add that once you have done that you type `:wq` which writes do disk (saves!) and quits vim.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suport JayUK !! yes its working and I found another way to do that using sed command " sed '/SMS2128301/d' "